# How to free and write to NULL a pointer in an array inside a struct, indirectly via pointer to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, null, children

I have to set a reference pointed by a pointer to NULL.
But the function `deleteP(...)` doesn't seem to work, indicated by the Output.
The functions `delete()` and `memoryset()` work in some way, even if the latter just fills the memory (pointed to by the pointer in the array) with zeroes.
I want the pointer in the array to finally be NULL and that is not working.

I need to do everything (i.e. set `fs->child[20]` to NULL etc.) via pointer to the struct (which is `el`in my code, a local pointer variable inside `deleteP(...)` ). This is because I am iterating over `fs` children, and their children after that, a lot of times, and I put the current child in `el`.

How could I solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT 255
#define LENGTH 256
#define MAX_CHILDREN 1024

typedef struct FS FS;
typedef struct Elem Elem;

struct Elem {
    char name[LENGTH];
    char content[256];
    int isFile;
    int emptyCells;
    Elem *child[MAX_CHILDREN];
};

struct FS {
    int emptyCells;
    Elem *child[MAX_CHILDREN];
};

void delete(FS *fs){
    free(fs->child[20]);
    fs->child[20] = NULL;
}

void deleteP(FS *fs){
    Elem *el = calloc(1, sizeof (Elem));
    el = fs->child[20];
    free(el);
    el = NULL;
}

void memoryset(FS *fs){
    Elem *el = calloc(1, sizeof (Elem));
    el = fs->child[20];
    memset(el, 0, sizeof(Elem));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {      

    FS *fs = calloc (1, sizeof(FS));
    fs->emptyCells = MAX_CHILDREN;
    fs->child[20] = calloc (1, sizeof(Elem));
    strcpy(fs->child[20]->name, "Hello");
    printf("No delete: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);

    memoryset(fs);
    printf("MEMSET: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);

    fs->child[20] = calloc (1, sizeof(Elem));
    strcpy(fs->child[20]->name, "Hello");
    delete(fs);
    printf("Delete: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);

    fs->child[20] = calloc (1, sizeof(Elem));
    strcpy(fs->child[20]->name, "Hello");
    deleteP(fs);
    printf("DeleteP: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);


}
```

Output:

```
No delete: Hello
MEMSET: 
Delete: (null)
DeleteP: Hello
```

Comment: In C a pointer can be `NULL`, but a reference can not once it has been assigned.

Comment: Could you rephrase? I don't get what you mean by " set a reference pointed by a pointer to NULL". Or maybe describe a situation example and what the result should be after what you try to do has been done.

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to set to NULL `fs->child[20]` which is pointed by `el`

Comment: @mikebayko Got it thank you! Do you think there's a way to bypass this or to do it in another way?

Comment: What (within the scope of C) is a reference?

Comment: @xing Yes that's right. But I don't think that that's the reason why `fs->child[20]` is not set to NULL

Comment: `delete(fs);
    printf("Delete: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);` and `deleteP(fs);
    printf("DeleteP: %s\n", fs->child[20]->name);` :  These are UB.

Comment: After `el = NULL;` I would be surprised if `el != NULL`. What makes you think it is not NULL?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why is that UB? Because it could execute `printf` before `delete`?

Comment: Do you expect `free(el);
    el = NULL;` to do anything to the memory pointed to by `el`?

Comment: @L.Carbini one dereference `NULL`. one using it after  `free`'d.

Comment: @Yunnosch `el` is NULL after that, but my goal was to make `fs->child[20]` become NULL too. I have to make `fs->child[20]` become NULL and I only have access to `el` in that portion of code.

Comment: And what happens with `*el = NULL; ` ?

Comment: @Yunnosch that was my idea, but it seems wrong now :p

Comment: It seems wrong now because...? Should not do it after free of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch `error: assigning to 'Elem' (aka 'struct Elem') from incompatible
      type 'void *'`

Comment: Would you like to edit that into your question? Or is it alread in there an I do not see it?

Comment: @Yunnosch I just changed this function: 

`void deleteP(FS *fs){
 Elem *el = calloc(1, sizeof (Elem));
 el = fs->child[20];
    free(el);
 *el = NULL;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150756/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-l-carbini).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you are calling `el=calloc()` only to set `el=fs->child` on the very next line, thus losing the reference to the memory that you just allocated.  That doesn't delete things, it creates memory leaks!

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Did you see the ticked comment by xing?

Comment: @Yunnosch Nope. Once it's past 5 comments I'm loathe to read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to phrase your goal in my words
(after verifying my understanding in chat):

- you want to free memory pointed to by a pointer which is stored in an array,
  which is inside a struct, which you get a pointer to
- you cannot access the array member directly,
  only via the pointer to the containing struct
- you also want to write NULL to the array member
- looking at your code, you attempted to do that by making a copy of the array member (which is a pointer)
- it mostly works, only that the array member does not end up being NULL
  (and some problems mentioned by xing and BLUEPIXY)

Basically, you need a pointer to the array member, instead of a copy of the array member.

So your function should be:

```
void deleteP(FS *fs){
    Elem **el; // pointer to pointer, instead of pointer (and no calloc)
    el = &(fs->child[20]); // pointer to array member
    free(*el); // free the pointer in the array member (not a copy of it),
               // though the effect is the same
    *el = NULL; // write NULL to the array member, not a copy of it,
                // this is what changes the effect to what you want 
}
```

If I did not mistype anything, this is more or less the result of our chat.
And as far as I understand, it solves your problem. Cheers.

As far as I can tell, this should also fix the memory leak found by xing inside `deleteP(...)`.
But be careful to also fix it in `memoryset(...)`.

This does NOT fix the problems of UB (undefined behaviour) as found by BLUEPIXY.
For this you need to rework your debug prints and make sure not to dereference any pointers to already freed memory (question of order of doing things) and also not to dereference any pointer which was set to NULL.

By the way, this could be done without a local pointer variable; doing everything via the parameter `fs`. But I kept the solution closer to your own code for better clarity of what is the difference. Also in my opinion your way of doing it via local pointer is more readable. It might even be faster, but seeing how good modern compilers are, I doubt it; the actual reason is clarity and readability.